# Split every cell at colon

Tags: split

I have a **tab** delimited file which contain **>1000** columns and rows. I want to split every cell at first colon (`:`) and extract the value. For instance:

***Sample Input***:

```
1   55  ./.:.:. 0|0:36:4    0|0:32:9    0|0:30:4    ./.:.:. ./.:.:. ./.:.:. 0|0:32:7
1   56  ./.:.:. ./.:.:. 0|0:32:9    0|0:30:4    ./.:.:. ./.:.:. ./.:.:. 0|0:32:7
```

***Sample output***:

```
1   55  ./. 0|0 0|0 0|0 ./. ./. ./. 0|0
1   56  ./. ./. 0|0 0|0 ./. ./. ./. 0|0
```

I can do this using `python` script:

`SHORT_col = ((str(cols[2]).split(':'))[0])`

But I wonder is there any **faster way** to do this, as calling **>1000** columns and processing using python script is time consuming. Your kind help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: More efficient how? Faster or better results?

Comment: Also, would be nicer to write `SHORT_col = cols[2].split(':')[0]`, should already be a string, and you have way too many brackets than needed

Comment: I mean faster way, as its quite time consuming to process python script, I am looking for some bash options may be awk or sed command

Comment: Maybe you should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my interpreation you need to remove the `:anything` (in regex it is: `:.*`) pattern from every field. With `awk` you can achieve this in the following way:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sub(/:.*/, "", $i); print }' your_data_file
```

Using the for loop it iterates through all the fields and repalce the defined pattern with an empty string `""` using `sub` function.

***Output***:

```
1 55 ./. 0|0 0|0 0|0 ./. ./. ./. 0|0
1 56 ./. ./. 0|0 0|0 ./. ./. ./. 0|0
```